# Casting generic lists

Tags: java, list, generics, instantiation

```
List<Integer> list0 = new List1<Integer>();
```

a) Is the word "List" a keyword in java??

b) When creating an object, shouldn't the name of the class be the same on both side?  For example:

```
Point x = new Point(1,2)
```

c) What does the following code mean?

```
List<Integer> list0 = new List1<Integer>();
```

Comment: I don;t think even this code compiles, unless List1 is implementation of List interface.

Comment: Also, unless you've defined `integer` yourself, I think you mean `Integer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List1` must be declared somewhere as

```
public class List1<T> implements List<T> {
...
```

`List` is an interface, so objects of any class that *implements* `List` can be assigned to a variable of type `List`.

Answer (score 8):

a) No, it isn't, it's an `Interface`

b) Not always. The type on the right has to be compatible with the one being assigned to - it must be the same, or a subtype. In this case `List1` must implement the `List` interface.

c) Create a new `List1` instance to hold Integers ("integer" is wrong - it must be "Integer"); this is only legal if the `List1` class implements the `List` interface. The `<Integer>` is a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) that restricts the types that the collection (List) can hold.

Comment: +1 from me, for the only one (so far) who addressed the (incorrect) use of generics.

Answer (score 2):

0) No. `List` is the name of an Interface. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

1) No. java has Polimorphism, so you can call an object by the name of one implemented Interface or an Extended Class

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface in java, you probably want to instantiate it to ArrayList.

```
List list0 = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

- A. List is an interface in Java.
- B. No the left hand side can be any super class or interface that the right hand side object extends or implements. Take a look at 'design by contract'
- C. Perhaps you mean

  List l = new ArrayList<>();

This is a list that can contain only Integer types

Answer (score 0):

[List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is not a keyword, it is a type, specifically, a Java interface.  The code in your example doesn't compile (unless the `List1` class is defined as: `class List1 implements List { ... }`), however something like this would:

```
List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This creates an `ArrayList` that can hold `Integers`, and assigns a reference to it to the variable `ls`, which is declared as the type `List<Integer>`.  `ls` could potentially hold a reference to a different type of list, such as a `LinkedList`, but you can guarantee that `ls` does point to some sort of list (unless it's null) and therefore you can use the methods specified in the `List` interface.

The type of the variable does not need to be the same as the type of the object on the right side of the assignment (though it often is), but the object must be either the same type, or a subclass/implementation of the variable type.  Since all objects extend `Object` you can always do something like:

```
Object obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Though, like above, the only methods you have access to from `obj` are what's defined in [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), even though the object being referred to is actually an `ArrayList`.